# How to test Android Application;s UI using Monkey

Tags: android, stress-testing, monkey

I am trying to test my Android app using [Monkey](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/monkey.html). There they say use this command,

`$ adb shell monkey -p your.package.name -v 500`

In my app, I have package name as travelceylon\client so if I give the command as:

`adb -e shell monkey -p travelceylon\client -v 1000`

...it will show errors like this:

```
:Monkey: seed=0 count=1000
:AllowPackage: travelceylonclient
:IncludeCategory: android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
:IncludeCategory: android.intent.category.MONKEY
** No activities found to run, monkey aborted.
```

So what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure your package name is spelled rightly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should separate the parts of your package name with dots:

```
adb -e shell monkey -p travelceylon.client -v 1000
```

As you can see in the error, it omits the `\` from the package name:

```
AllowPackage: travelceylonclient :IncludeCategory: 
                          ^ ???
```